# Virto Commerce Azure Empty Roles list

Tags: api, azure, hmac, user-roles, virtocommerce

I am trying to install the store front directly to Azure from github.  One of the required fields on the installation form is Virto Commerce Api Hmac App Id.  I think the generation of this code requires the 'Use Api' role in the user manager.

My problem is that the Available Roles list is empty in my Azure installation of the platform manager.

How do I populate this list with the built in Roles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it appears you have installed VC platform without sample data.

Because VC storefront interacted with platform only via API you should generate new Hmac security key for `frontend` user and enter it in `Virto Commerce Api Hmac App Id` on storefront installation wizard.
For generate new Hmac security key please do follow steps.

**Open Configuration-> Security-> Users-> Click on `frontend` user -> API keys -> Click on Frontend(Hmac)-> Generate**

[image]